# In f- statistic :Why do we multiply the Sum of squares with the sample size?

Tags: f-statistic

In the f statistic formula
In the numerator, why do we multiply the sum of squares with the sample size?!
Scenic we are interested only in the variation of sample means from the grand mean.
[image: formula of f statistic]

Comment: Ahmed, could you write down the formula to which you are referring?

Comment: I added a pic of the formula to the post

Comment: Thanks. There's a difference between capital $N$ and lower case $n$. Can you tell what it is?

Comment: n: is the sample size (we assume that all samples of the same size),.                                            N: is the total number of values from all samples

Comment: Thanks, does it make sense that the numerator is summing over all individuals due to the inclusion of the $n$ factor, just like how the denominator is summing over all individuals?